# How to filter createdAt from current date to 90 days ago?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to filter the results of a listing for the last 90 days, but I don't know how to do it.
It currently looks like this:

```
const initialFilter = [
  {
    term: {
      createdAt: Date.now || new Date(Date.now() - 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: What does the data you're filtering look like?  You can do `<` and `>` comparisons of Date objects, and new Date(Date.now() - 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) gives you the right point in time to compare against.

Answer (score 2):

You can do arithmetic operations with date like `<` or `>`.

Example

```
const dateOne = new Date()
const dateTwo = new Date("02/01/2021")
const dateThree = new Date("01/01/2022")
const dateToCompare = new Date(Date.now() - 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

console.log(dateToCompare > dateTwo)
console.log(dateToCompare > dateOne)
console.log(dateToCompare > dateThree)
console.log(dateToCompare < dateThree)
```